# Wrapping chars in caesar cipher encode

Tags: c++, c, ascii

Can anyone please explain me how this wrapping of chars between a-to-z and A-to-Z happening in Caesar shift code?

```
k %= 26;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int c = s[i];
    if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){
        c += k;
        if( c > 'z'){
            c = 96 + (c % 122); // wrapping from z to a?
        }
    }
    else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
        c += k;
        if(c > 'Z'){
            c = 64 + (c % 90);
        }
    }
    cout << (char)c;
}
```

K is amount of shift and c is a char of string s.

Is there any better way to do the same?

Comment: Simple google search and this [link](http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~crypto/historical/caesar.html) help you. Why have you asked before searching ?

Comment: Code has additional issues if `k < 0`.  Suggest `k %= 26; if (k < 0) k += 26;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets make a couple changes to the code and it is easier to see what is going on

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int c = s[i];
    if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){
        c += k;
        if( c > 'z'){
            c = 'a' + (c % 'z') - 1; // wrapping from z to a?
        }
    }
    else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'){
        c += k;
        if(c > 'Z'){
            c = 'A' + (c % 'Z') - 1;
        }
    }
    cout << (char)c;
}
```

So in `c = 'a' + (c % 'z') - 1;` if `c` is larger than `z` then we mod `c` by `z`(122) to get how many characters from `a` we need to go.  The same thing is going on with the upper case letters.  I am subtracting one here as we are starting at `a` instead of the character before `a` like you original code does.

Comment: This will have trouble with `k<0`.  But maybe OP does not care about that.

Comment: Note: `c = 'a' + (c % 'z') - 1` is only doing a `c -= ('z'-'a'+1)` or `c -= 26`.  IMO, one of these 2 would be clearer.